# Mysql memory usage growing until OOM and system kills / restarts

Tags: mysql, database-tuning

I have MySQL 5.7.27 under Ubuntu 16.04.4, 64 bit, 4GB RAM and SSDs (it's a virtual machine). I am observing resident memory growth in mysqld until no more resources are available and the OS kills / restarts mysqld.

**Some background** - The system is used to collect information from remote locations, with 1 entity being collected from each location. Each entity might have many hundreds of data points. For each remote location, there are two databases, which supports two situations: each location is per customer (but one customer might have many - thousands - of such locations) and in some situations, it might be many thousands of entities being collected from each remote location. The two DBs correspond to raw data collected and "processed" summaries. In addition, there is one additional DB per customer recording admin and other data about each remote location. So, total DB count is C * ( 1 + 2L ) - C for customer, L for location. The first DB of 2L has 32 tables and a minimum size of 2MB (but I have at least one example which it 5.9GB - not in this current sample set) - it is "cleared" at the start of each collection event; the second has 12 tables and typical size in the current sample set is 1MB (although this accumulates for each collection event).

A remote collection is performed periodically, say once a week or once a month, per remote location. After each collection, a process is run to summarise data from the ALL of the 2L databases into the one unifying one.

In the system with the issue, there are C ( 1 + 2L ) equaling just over 5000. When the summarisation process is run, mysqld resident memory (viewed using `top`) grows from around 800MB to just under 3GB. The summarisation process completes and might then run again a short time afterwards. That process completes cleanly and correctly releases query results and closes DB connections. The application is PHP 7.2.24 CLI running locally (so, using sockets, not TCP).

I have tried "tuning":

```
open_files_limit = 11000
table_open_cache = 5200

innodb_lru_scan_depth = 128
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1073741824
```

(see [open_files_limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_open_files_limit), [table_open_cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_open_cache), [innodb_lru_scan_depth](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lru_scan_depth), [innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit), [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size))

These either made no apparent change or worsened the rate of growth of memory usage. I also ran `show engine performance_schema status;` at three instances: when resident memory was at 2459MB, 2478MB and 2910MB. Between those three samples, I saw differences only in the following metrics:

```
                                2459MB       2478MB        2910MB

(digest_hash).count             4676 ->      4837 ->       4958
(filename_hash).count         121118 ->    121139 ->     121214
(table_share_hash).count       27229 ->     27247 ->      27276
mutex_instances.count          29696 ->     30720 ->      31744
mutex_instances.memory       3801088 ->   3932160 ->    4063232
performance_scheme.memory  426293432 -> 426424504 -> 4266886648
rwlock_instances.count        400384 ->    400384 ->     401408
rwlock_instances.memory     51249152 ->  51249152 ->   51380224
```

My expectation is that at the end of each summarisation run, either "temporary" buffer space in mysqld would be freed up, or would simply be reused at the next run of that process, given that it effectively is making the same sequence of queries (and very similar updates) across the same set of databases / tables. The fact that the memory footprint grows suggest to me that either there is a memory leak in mysqld, or that an intentional "buffer" related to some failure condition (connections, locks, mutexes?) is at least part of the cause of the memory growth. I suggest the latter, because I would look at what would persist in mysqld between subsequent runs of that summarisation process.

I have also tried running mysqltuner.pl (see http://mysqltuner.com), but this also causes the memory growth problem, which is undoubtedly related to the number of databases. However, if I might refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/database-count-limit.html, whatever limit MySQL might or might not have to the number of databases and tables, the numbers here are not significant to mysqld itself, even if they might be to the underlying OS. I confess I was impressed that the server was apparently handling over 1000 `SELECTS` per second on a not very highly spec'd system.

**So**, What "monitoring" parameters should I be looking at to assist with tuning mysql, the OS or platform and what (mysql / OS) tuning parameters would be most helpful in this situation? I could just take the [Jaws](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073195/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) approach (["We're going to need a bigger boat"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTMxZxI7-SQ)), but if the issue I'm experiencing **is** a memory leak, then just adding more RAM is only just postponing the inevitable.

------------ EDIT following answer by Rick James (2020/01/13) -
RAM - 4GB

SHOW VARIABLES; (less SSL related info) output:

```
auto_generate_certs  ON
auto_increment_increment    1
auto_increment_offset   1
autocommit   ON
automatic_sp_privileges  ON
avoid_temporal_upgrade   OFF
back_log    80
basedir  /usr/
big_tables   OFF
bind_address     *
binlog_cache_size   32768
binlog_checksum  CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates  OFF
binlog_error_action  ABORT_SERVER
binlog_format    ROW
binlog_group_commit_sync_delay  0
binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count 0
binlog_gtid_simple_recovery  ON
binlog_max_flush_queue_time 0
binlog_order_commits     ON
binlog_row_image     FULL
binlog_rows_query_log_events     OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768
binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size  25000
binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking   COMMIT_ORDER
block_encryption_mode    aes-128-ecb
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
character_set_client     utf8mb4
character_set_connection     utf8mb4
character_set_database   utf8
character_set_filesystem     binary
character_set_results    utf8mb4
character_set_server     utf8
character_set_system     utf8
character_sets_dir   /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
check_proxy_users    OFF
collation_connection     utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database   utf8_unicode_ci
collation_server     utf8_unicode_ci
completion_type  NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert    AUTO
connect_timeout 10
core_file    OFF
datadir  /var/lib/mysql/
date_format  %Y-%m-%d
datetime_format  %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default_authentication_plugin    mysql_native_password
default_password_lifetime   0
default_storage_engine   InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine   InnoDB
default_week_format 0
delay_key_write  ON
delayed_insert_limit    100
delayed_insert_timeout  300
delayed_queue_size  1000
disabled_storage_engines     
disconnect_on_expired_password   ON
div_precision_increment 4

end_markers_in_json  OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency     OFF
eq_range_index_dive_limit   200
error_count 0
event_scheduler  OFF
expire_logs_days    10
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp  OFF
external_user    
flush    OFF
flush_time  0
foreign_key_checks   ON
ft_boolean_syntax    + -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len 84
ft_min_word_len 4
ft_query_expansion_limit    20
ft_stopword_file     (built-in)
general_log  OFF
general_log_file     /var/lib/mysql/demo.log
group_concat_max_len    1024
gtid_executed_compression_period    1000
gtid_mode    OFF
gtid_next    AUTOMATIC
gtid_owned   
gtid_purged  
have_compress    YES
have_crypt   YES
have_dynamic_loading     YES
have_geometry    YES
have_openssl     YES
have_profiling   YES
have_query_cache     YES
have_rtree_keys  YES
have_ssl     YES
have_statement_timeout   YES
have_symlink     YES
host_cache_size 279
hostname    <hidden>
identity    0
ignore_builtin_innodb    OFF
ignore_db_dirs   
init_connect     
init_file    
init_slave   
innodb_adaptive_flushing     ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index   ON
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts    8
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval   5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock   OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog     OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl    OFF
innodb_api_trx_level    0
innodb_autoextend_increment 64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size   134217728
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown  ON
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now  OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct 25
innodb_buffer_pool_filename  ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    1
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort    OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup   ON
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now  OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size 134217728
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
innodb_change_buffering  all
innodb_checksum_algorithm    crc32
innodb_checksums     ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled     OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    5
innodb_compression_level    6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50
innodb_concurrency_tickets  5000
innodb_data_file_path    ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir     
innodb_deadlock_detect   ON
innodb_default_row_format    dynamic
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache   OFF
innodb_doublewrite   ON
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_format   Barracuda
innodb_file_format_check     ON
innodb_file_format_max   Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table    ON
innodb_fill_factor  100
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  2
innodb_flush_method  
innodb_flush_neighbors  1
innodb_flush_sync    ON
innodb_flushing_avg_loops   30
innodb_force_load_corrupted  OFF
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_ft_aux_table  
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print  OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword    ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84
innodb_ft_min_token_size    3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table  
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size  640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table    
innodb_io_capacity  200
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
innodb_large_prefix  ON
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog   OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  16777216
innodb_log_checksums     ON
innodb_log_compressed_pages  ON
innodb_log_file_size    50331648
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_group_home_dir    ./
innodb_log_write_ahead_size 8192
innodb_lru_scan_depth   128
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  75
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  0
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay  0
innodb_max_undo_log_size    1073741824
innodb_monitor_disable   
innodb_monitor_enable    
innodb_monitor_reset     
innodb_monitor_reset_all     
innodb_numa_interleave   OFF
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728
innodb_open_files   5200
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only    OFF
innodb_page_cleaners    1
innodb_page_size    16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks   OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size 300
innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency    128
innodb_purge_threads    4
innodb_random_read_ahead     OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
innodb_read_io_threads  4
innodb_read_only     OFF
innodb_replication_delay    0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout   OFF
innodb_rollback_segments    128
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc     ON
innodb_stats_include_delete_marked   OFF
innodb_stats_method  nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata     OFF
innodb_stats_persistent  ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20
innodb_stats_sample_pages   8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8
innodb_status_output     OFF
innodb_status_output_locks   OFF
innodb_strict_mode   ON
innodb_support_xa    ON
innodb_sync_array_size  1
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30
innodb_table_locks   ON
innodb_temp_data_file_path   ibtmp1:12M:autoextend
innodb_thread_concurrency   0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   10000
innodb_tmpdir    
innodb_undo_directory    ./
innodb_undo_log_truncate     OFF
innodb_undo_logs    128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
innodb_use_native_aio    ON
innodb_version   5.7.28
innodb_write_io_threads 4
insert_id   0
interactive_timeout 28800
internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine     InnoDB
join_buffer_size    262144
keep_files_on_create     OFF
key_buffer_size 16777216
key_cache_age_threshold 300
key_cache_block_size    1024
key_cache_division_limit    100
keyring_operations   ON
large_files_support  ON
large_page_size 0
large_pages  OFF
last_insert_id  0
lc_messages  en_US
lc_messages_dir  /usr/share/mysql/
lc_time_names    en_US
license  GPL
local_infile     ON
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
locked_in_memory     OFF
log_bin  OFF
log_bin_basename     
log_bin_index    
log_bin_trust_function_creators  OFF
log_bin_use_v1_row_events    OFF
log_builtin_as_identified_by_password    OFF
log_error    /var/log/mysql/error.log
log_error_verbosity 3
log_output   FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes    OFF
log_slave_updates    OFF
log_slow_admin_statements    OFF
log_slow_slave_statements    OFF
log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog     ON
log_syslog   OFF
log_syslog_facility  daemon
log_syslog_include_pid   ON
log_syslog_tag   
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes  0
log_timestamps   UTC
log_warnings    2
long_query_time 10
low_priority_updates     OFF
lower_case_file_system   OFF
lower_case_table_names  0
master_info_repository   FILE
master_verify_checksum   OFF
max_allowed_packet  16777216
max_binlog_cache_size   1.84467440737095E+019
max_binlog_size 104857600
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size  1.84467440737095E+019
max_connect_errors  100
max_connections 151
max_delayed_threads 20
max_digest_length   1024
max_error_count 64
max_execution_time  0
max_heap_table_size 16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads  20
max_join_size   1.84467440737096E+019
max_length_for_sort_data    1024
max_points_in_geometry  65536
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
max_relay_log_size  0
max_seeks_for_key   1.84467440737096E+019
max_sort_length 1024
max_sp_recursion_depth  0
max_tmp_tables  32
max_user_connections    0
max_write_lock_count    1.84467440737096E+019
metadata_locks_cache_size   1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances   8
min_examined_row_limit  0
multi_range_count   256
myisam_data_pointer_size    6
myisam_max_sort_file_size   9.22337203685373E+018
myisam_mmap_size    1.84467440737096E+019
myisam_recover_options   BACKUP
myisam_repair_threads   1
myisam_sort_buffer_size 8388608
myisam_stats_method  nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap  OFF
mysql_native_password_proxy_users    OFF
net_buffer_length   16384
net_read_timeout    30
net_retry_count 10
net_write_timeout   60
new  OFF
ngram_token_size    2
offline_mode     OFF
old  OFF
old_alter_table  OFF
old_passwords   0
open_files_limit    11000
optimizer_prune_level   1
optimizer_search_depth  62
optimizer_switch     index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on
optimizer_trace  enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features     greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on
optimizer_trace_limit   1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size    16384
optimizer_trace_offset  -1
parser_max_mem_size 1.84467440737096E+019
performance_schema   ON
performance_schema_accounts_size    -1
performance_schema_digests_size 10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size  10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size   10
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size  10000
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size   10
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size    10000
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size 10
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size   10000
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size    10
performance_schema_hosts_size   -1
performance_schema_max_cond_classes 80
performance_schema_max_cond_instances   -1
performance_schema_max_digest_length    1024
performance_schema_max_file_classes 80
performance_schema_max_file_handles 32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances   -1
performance_schema_max_index_stat   -1
performance_schema_max_memory_classes   320
performance_schema_max_metadata_locks   -1
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes    210
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances    -1
performance_schema_max_program_instances    -1
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes   50
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances -1
performance_schema_max_socket_classes   10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances -1
performance_schema_max_sql_text_length  1024
performance_schema_max_stage_classes    150
performance_schema_max_statement_classes    193
performance_schema_max_statement_stack  10
performance_schema_max_table_handles    -1
performance_schema_max_table_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat  -1
performance_schema_max_thread_classes   50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances -1
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size   512
performance_schema_setup_actors_size    -1
performance_schema_setup_objects_size   -1
performance_schema_users_size   -1
pid_file     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
plugin_dir   /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/
port    3306
preload_buffer_size 32768
profiling    OFF
profiling_history_size  15
protocol_version    10
proxy_user   
pseudo_slave_mode    OFF
pseudo_thread_id    8224
query_alloc_block_size  8192
query_cache_limit   1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
query_cache_size    16777216
query_cache_type     OFF
query_cache_wlock_invalidate     OFF
query_prealloc_size 8192
rand_seed1  0
rand_seed2  0
range_alloc_block_size  4096
range_optimizer_max_mem_size    8388608
rbr_exec_mode    STRICT
read_buffer_size    131072
read_only    OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size    262144
relay_log    
relay_log_basename   /var/lib/mysql/demo-relay-bin
relay_log_index  /var/lib/mysql/demo-relay-bin.index
relay_log_info_file  relay-log.info
relay_log_info_repository    FILE
relay_log_purge  ON
relay_log_recovery   OFF
relay_log_space_limit   0
report_host  
report_password  
report_port 3306
report_user  
require_secure_transport     ON
rpl_stop_slave_timeout  31536000
secure_auth  ON
secure_file_priv     /var/lib/mysql-files/
server_id   0
server_id_bits  32
server_uuid <hidden>
session_track_gtids  OFF
session_track_schema     ON
session_track_state_change   OFF
session_track_system_variables   time_zone,autocommit,character_set_client,character_set_results,character_set_connection
session_track_transaction_info   OFF
sha256_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys   ON
sha256_password_private_key_path     private_key.pem
sha256_password_proxy_users  OFF
sha256_password_public_key_path  public_key.pem
show_compatibility_56    OFF
show_create_table_verbosity  OFF
show_old_temporals   OFF
skip_external_locking    ON
skip_name_resolve    OFF
skip_networking  OFF
skip_show_database   OFF
slave_allow_batching     OFF
slave_checkpoint_group  512
slave_checkpoint_period 300
slave_compressed_protocol    OFF
slave_exec_mode  STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir    /tmp
slave_max_allowed_packet    1073741824
slave_net_timeout   60
slave_parallel_type  DATABASE
slave_parallel_workers  0
slave_pending_jobs_size_max 16777216
slave_preserve_commit_order  OFF
slave_rows_search_algorithms     TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
slave_skip_errors    OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum    ON
slave_transaction_retries   10
slave_type_conversions   
slow_launch_time    2
slow_query_log   OFF
slow_query_log_file  /var/lib/mysql/demo-slow.log
socket   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
sort_buffer_size    262144
sql_auto_is_null     OFF
sql_big_selects  ON
sql_buffer_result    OFF
sql_log_bin  ON
sql_log_off  OFF
sql_mode     ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_notes    ON
sql_quote_show_create    ON
sql_safe_updates     OFF
sql_select_limit    1.84467440737096E+019
sql_slave_skip_counter  0
sql_warnings     OFF
stored_program_cache    256
super_read_only  OFF
sync_binlog 1
sync_frm     ON
sync_master_info    10000
sync_relay_log  10000
sync_relay_log_info 10000
system_time_zone     GMT
table_definition_cache  2000
table_open_cache    5200
table_open_cache_instances  16
thread_cache_size   8
thread_handling  one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack    262144
time_format  %H:%i:%s
time_zone    SYSTEM
timestamp   1579095336.07864
tls_version  TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
tmp_table_size  16777216
tmpdir   /tmp
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192
transaction_allow_batching   OFF
transaction_isolation    REPEATABLE-READ
transaction_prealloc_size   4096
transaction_read_only    OFF
transaction_write_set_extraction     OFF
tx_isolation     REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only     OFF
unique_checks    ON
updatable_views_with_limit   YES
version  5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
version_comment  (Ubuntu)
version_compile_machine  x86_64
version_compile_os   Linux
wait_timeout    28800
warning_count   0
```

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; (less SSL related info and any com_*=0 values) output:

```
Aborted_clients 0
Aborted_connects    4
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
Bytes_received  120596117
Bytes_sent  423055987
Com_admin_commands  1422
Com_change_db   1969
Com_delete  26
Com_delete_multi    5
Com_flush   5
Com_insert  543
Com_lock_tables 106103
Com_select  290121
Com_set_option  3952
Com_show_charsets   4
Com_show_fields 1756
Com_show_keys   3
Com_show_plugins    1
Com_show_status 2317
Com_show_tables 4
Com_show_variables  10
Com_unlock_tables   106103
Com_update  119462
Connection_errors_accept    0
Connection_errors_internal  0
Connection_errors_max_connections   0
Connection_errors_peer_address  0
Connection_errors_select    0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap   0
Connections 53918
Created_tmp_disk_tables 7205
Created_tmp_files   6
Created_tmp_tables  26682
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  516258
Handler_delete  605
Handler_discover    0
Handler_external_lock   1131715
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  251891
Handler_read_key    1450835
Handler_read_last   0
Handler_read_next   46912240
Handler_read_prev   0
Handler_read_rnd    333804
Handler_read_rnd_next   77706400
Handler_rollback    0
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  20612
Handler_write   139820
Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status   Dumping of buffer pool not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status   Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200110 15:44:11
Innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status     
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   7744
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   126877696
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  0
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    10525
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   128
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   319
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  8191
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   2174
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   552
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    92861248
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    230500
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   490867
Innodb_data_fsyncs  6682
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    3812250112
Innodb_data_reads   257019
Innodb_data_writes  36166
Innodb_data_written 301705728
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  5776
Innodb_dblwr_writes 1121
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests   24009
Innodb_log_writes   23298
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    3651
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   34017280
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    388
Innodb_pages_read   232676
Innodb_pages_written    10525
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    0
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    0
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    0
Innodb_row_lock_waits   0
Innodb_rows_deleted 605
Innodb_rows_inserted    33914
Innodb_rows_read    125144394
Innodb_rows_updated 20612
Innodb_num_open_files   5200
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Innodb_available_undo_logs  128
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
Key_blocks_unused   13396
Key_blocks_used 3
Key_read_requests   6
Key_reads   3
Key_write_requests  0
Key_writes  0
Locked_connects 0
Max_execution_time_exceeded 0
Max_execution_time_set  0
Max_execution_time_set_failed   0
Max_used_connections    14
Max_used_connections_time   10/01/20 15:50
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Ongoing_anonymous_transaction_count 0
Open_files  0
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  3464
Open_tables 5200
Opened_files    337104
Opened_table_definitions    140571
Opened_tables   76095
Performance_schema_accounts_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_digest_lost  0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_hosts_lost   0
Performance_schema_index_stat_lost  0
Performance_schema_locker_lost  0
Performance_schema_memory_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_metadata_lock_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_nested_statement_lost    0
Performance_schema_prepared_statements_lost 0
Performance_schema_program_lost 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost   0
Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_table_lock_stat_lost 0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_users_lost   0
Prepared_stmt_count 0
Qcache_free_blocks  1
Qcache_free_memory  16760152
Qcache_hits 0
Qcache_inserts  0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   184049
Qcache_queries_in_cache 0
Qcache_total_blocks 1
Queries 687716
Questions   684326
Rsa_public_key  <removed>
Select_full_join    2827
Select_full_range_join  319
Select_range    56255
Select_range_check  1525
Select_scan 156904
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    0
Sort_merge_passes   0
Sort_range  61935
Sort_rows   116417
Sort_scan   99600
Table_locks_immediate   458
Table_locks_waited  0
Table_open_cache_hits   381570
Table_open_cache_misses 76095
Table_open_cache_overflows  70888
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    0
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threads_cached  7
Threads_connected   3
Threads_created 14
Threads_running 1
Uptime  424288
Uptime_since_flush_status   424288
```

Comment: InnoDB buffer_pool (which is good thing) lets the RAM usage grow..  InnoDB buffer_pool makes MySQL more or less perform as a memory engine that is one of the main reason why it handled that much...

Comment: The trick is configuring it right that the buffer pool does not take up all your RAM safe limits to configure are around 75% - 80% of the total system RAM, you could go a bit lower and use 70% if you think it is saver.. As other things in MySQL can also use op RAM under the hood per execution like the parser/execution , [internal temporary RAM based tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) for some resultsets.... Not to forget about temporary tables created with `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ..`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  If you are not swapping and not crashing, there is nothing to worry about.  But, since OOM is killing it, then something needs to be tuned lower.

Long answer...

Change `swappiness` to 1.  (It may be defaulted to 60.)

For only 4GB of RAM, do not set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 75-80% of RAM as someone else suggested.  You will run out of RAM.  Swapping is terrible for performance.  Leave it at 1G for now.  And this assumes you do not have any other applications running on the machine.

The buffer_pool grows but does not shrink.  It is reused.  It is a "cache" for blocks of data and indexes of the various tables you are working on.

It sounds like 400MB is chewed up by `performance_schema`.  If you are not using that, turn it off.  If you are using it, then lower the buffer_pool to 1000M to make room for PS.

`table_open_cache = 5200` -- Do you have thousands of tables?  Perhaps 1000 would be safer.

Dozens, even hundreds, of databases is not a problem.  `table_open_cache` is a cache, so it does not need to be as large as the number of tables you have.  But, since there are multiple entries for one table when multiple connections are looking at that table, it can be too small.

For further analysis, please provide the info discussed here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning  I will see if there are further clues in the VARIABLES and GLOBAL STATUS.

1K qps is moderately busy (~70th percentile); 10K gets more exciting.  Since you seem to have bursts of activity, perhaps you are hitting 10K?

I am not a fan of "throwing hardware at a problem".

**An analysis of the settings**

**Observations:**

```
* Version: 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
* 4 GB of RAM
* Uptime = 4d 21:51:28
* Are you sure this was a SHOW GLOBAL STATUS ?
* You are not running on Windows.
* Running 64-bit version
* You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.
```

**The More Important Issues:**

Do not use `LOCK TABLES` / `UNLOCK TABLES` with InnoDB.  Use transactions.  (Or, let's discuss why you are using them.)

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G  -- or lower if you have a lot of other apps running -- Caution:  1G would make the OOM issue worse, so don't do this until figuring out the OOM problem.

Your system seems to be rather lightly loaded -- except for the number of tables that are open.  Can you elaborate on what the app does?

Possibly a lot of inefficient queries.  Set long_query_time = 1 and turn on the slowlog.

**Details and other observations:**

`( (key_buffer_size / 0.20 + innodb_buffer_pool_size / 0.70) ) = ((16M / 0.20 + 128M / 0.70)) / 4096M = 6.4%` -- Most of available ram should be made available for caching.
-- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

`( table_open_cache ) = 5,200` -- Number of table descriptors to cache
-- Several hundred is usually good.

`( Table_open_cache_misses / (Table_open_cache_hits + Table_open_cache_misses) ) = 76,095 / (381570 + 76095) = 16.6%` -- Effectiveness of table_open_cache.
-- Increase table_open_cache (now 5200) and check table_open_cache_instances (now 16).

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 128M` -- InnoDB Data + Index cache
-- 128M (an old default) is woefully small.

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted / Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead ) = 552 / 2174 = 25.4%` -- Utility of read_ahead.
-- Turn off innodb_random_read_ahead (now OFF).

`( Innodb_dblwr_pages_written/Innodb_pages_written ) = 5,776/10525 = 54.9%` -- Seems like these values should be equal?

`( Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group / innodb_log_file_size ) = 34,017,280 / (424288 / 3600) / 2 / 48M = 0.00287` -- Ratio
-- (see minutes)

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 424,288 / 60 * 48M / 34017280 = 10,462` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size (now 50331648). (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( innodb_flush_method ) = innodb_flush_method =` -- How InnoDB should ask the OS to write blocks. Suggest O_DIRECT or O_ALL_DIRECT (Percona) to avoid double buffering. (At least for Unix.) See chrischandler for caveat about O_ALL_DIRECT

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( character_set_server ) = character_set_server = utf8`
-- Charset problems may be helped by setting character_set_server (now utf8) to utf8mb4. That is the future default.

`( net_buffer_length / max_allowed_packet ) = 16,384 / 16M = 0.10%`

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 156,904 / 290121 = 54.1%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( innodb_autoinc_lock_mode ) = 1` -- Galera: desires 2 -- 2 = "interleaved"; 1 = "consecutive" is typical; 0 = "traditional".
-- Galera desires 2; 2 requires BINLOG_FORMAT=ROW or MIXED

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( log_slow_slave_statements ) = log_slow_slave_statements = OFF` -- (5.6.11, 5.7.1) By default, replicated statements won't show up in the slowlog; this causes them to show.
-- It can be helpful in the slowlog to see writes that could be interfering with Slave reads.

`( back_log ) = 80` -- (Autosized as of 5.6.6; based on max_connections)
-- Raising to min(150, max_connections (now 151)) may help when doing lots of connections.

You have the Query Cache half-off. You should set both query_cache_type = OFF and query_cache_size = 0 . There is (according to a rumor) a 'bug' in the QC code that leaves some code on unless you turn off both of those settings.

**Abnormally small:**

```
Com_insert = 4.6 /HR
Created_tmp_files = 0.051 /HR
Handler_write = 0.33 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data = 299 /sec
Key_read_requests = 0.051 /HR
Key_reads+Key_writes + Innodb_pages_read+Innodb_pages_written+Innodb_dblwr_writes+Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed = 0.6 /sec
Open_files = 0
Table_locks_immediate = 3.9 /HR
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Com_unlock_tables = 0.25 /sec
Innodb_num_open_files = 5,200
Open_table_definitions = 3,464
Open_tables = 5,200
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes = 50
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
optimizer_trace = enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features = greedy_search=on, range_optimizer=on, dynamic_range=on, repeated_subselect=on
require_secure_transport = ON
slave_rows_search_algorithms = TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
```

Comment: Rick James: That's a helpful response. I have added the "dump" type info roughly according to your website to end of the post (tab separated lines, so reasonably machine readable). I've also made some of the suggested changes you propose; will test and report back. Thanks

Comment: Post changes: mysqld is still growing. The swappiness change means the system is still usable (until killed by OOM). The turning off of performance_schema frees up memory thus just pospoing when OOM happens. The databases don't have that many tables each, it's just that there are thousands of databases, although only about 5 or so need to be connected to at the same time for one set of queries.

Comment: @MarkBradley - I analyzed the settings.  Sorry, I still don't have a solid answer to the OOM issue.